# Method in admin tool deleting all contents of file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I created a user tool that will allow admins of a forum to add, edit, and delete users from their desktop, then give them the ability to upload a file into their database. I'm aware that this should be done straight to a database, but the people I'm making it for don't want me to have access.

This is the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'
require 'open-uri'

def menu
    print "Welcome to User Menu. Would you like to [A]dd users, [D]elete users, [E]dit users, [V]iew all users, or [Q]uit the system?\n"
    input = gets.chomp!
    case input
    when /a/i
        add_user
    when /d/i
        delete_user
    when /e/i
        edit_user
    when /v/i
        view_all
    else
        puts "Exiting system.."
        exit
    end
end

def add_user
    data = { username: prompt("Enter username:"), 
             email_address: prompt("Enter email:"), 
             member_status: prompt("Enter member status:") }
    File.open('users.yml', 'a') { |s| s.write(data.to_yaml) }
    add_user if restart
end

def delete_user
    hash = YAML.load_file('users.yml')
    delete_data = { username: prompt("Enter username:" ),
                    email_address: prompt("Enter email:" ),
                    member_status: prompt("Enter member status:" ) }
    File.open('users.yml', 'w'){ |f| f.dump(hash.to_yaml)}
end
#I literally want to punch a baby right now..

def edit_user
    #Still in process of creating
    edit_user if restart
end

def view_all
    content = URI('#left blank for security of site').read
end

def restart
    puts "Would you like to edit another user?"
    input = gets.chomp
    if input =~ /yes/i
        return true
    else
        puts "Exiting program.."
        exit
    end
end

def prompt ( message )
    puts message
    gets.chomp
end
menu
```

YAML file example:

```
---
:username: TEST
:email_address: TEST
:member_status: TEST
---
:username: TEST1
:email_address: TEST1
:member_status: TEST1
```

I'm having some trouble with the `delete_user` method. Either it deletes the entire content of the file, or it doesn't work at all. I've tried rewriting it multiple times:

```
def delete_user
    delete_data = { username: prompt("Enter username:") ,
                    email_address: prompt("Enter email:"),
                    member_status: prompt("Enter member status:") }
                    hash = YAML.load_file('users.yml')
                    hash.delete[username]
                    hash.delete[email_address]
                    hash.delete[status]
    File.open('users.yml', 'w'){ |f| f.dump(delete_data.to_yaml)}
end 
    #Found out why this one wasn't working due to me 
    #adding the wrong data to the hash
    #was also giving argument error.
```

I've also tried taking out the `File.open` aspect, which in turn doesn't really make any sense, but it was worth a shot:

```
 def delete_user
    delete_data = { username: prompt("Enter username:") ,
                    email_address: prompt("Enter email:"),
                    member_status: prompt("Enter member status:") }
                    hash.delete[username]
                    hash.delete[email_address]
                    hash.delete[status]
     hash = YAML.load_file('users.yml', 'w') { |f| f.dump(delete_data.to_yaml) }
end
#Really doesn't make sense so I ended
#up using the following one
```

Right now I have this:

```
def delete_user
    hash = YAML.load_file('users.yml')
    delete_data = { username: prompt("Enter username:" ),
                    email_address: prompt("Enter email:" ),
                    member_status: prompt("Enter member status:" ) }
    File.open('users.yml', 'w'){ |f| f.dump(hash.to_yaml)}
end
```

I am at a loss for what to try next. I've Googled it, rewritten it, etc. How do I get `delete_user` to delete just the user given by the operator of the program, and not delete the entire file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these:

```
require 'yaml'

puts YAML.load(
'---
:username: TEST
:email_address: TEST
:member_status: TEST
---
:username: TEST1
:email_address: TEST1
:member_status: TEST1
'
)

# >> {:username=>"TEST", :email_address=>"TEST", :member_status=>"TEST"}
```

By default YAML only loads a single document. Only `TEST` (the first document) is returned. Removing the document marker:

```
require 'yaml'

puts YAML.load(
    '---
    :username: TEST
    :email_address: TEST
    :member_status: TEST
    :username: TEST1
    :email_address: TEST1
    :member_status: TEST1
    '
)
# >> {:username=>"TEST1", :email_address=>"TEST1", :member_status=>"TEST1"}
```

After loading, all your `TEST1` entries have stomped on the `TEST` entries.

You can use a different method to load the data:

```
require 'yaml'

users = YAML.load_stream(
'---
:username: TEST
:email_address: TEST
:member_status: TEST
---
:username: TEST1
:email_address: TEST1
:member_status: TEST1
'
)
users
# => [{:username=>"TEST", :email_address=>"TEST", :member_status=>"TEST"},
#     {:username=>"TEST1", :email_address=>"TEST1", :member_status=>"TEST1"}]
```

Or you need a different structure.

When creating YAML, I always start with Ruby, or the language I'm writing in, and use it to create my structure, then have YAML serialize it so I can see what the file should look like. A quick test using round-trip code then helps me see that things are working correctly.

```
require 'yaml'

users = [
  {:username=>"TEST", :email_address=>"TEST", :member_status=>"TEST"},
  {:username=>"TEST1", :email_address=>"TEST1", :member_status=>"TEST1"}
]

puts users.to_yaml

# >> ---
# >> - :username: TEST
# >>   :email_address: TEST
# >>   :member_status: TEST
# >> - :username: TEST1
# >>   :email_address: TEST1
# >>   :member_status: TEST1
```

Or:

```
require 'yaml'

users = {
  'TEST' => {:email_address=>"TEST", :member_status=>"TEST"},
  'TEST1' => {:email_address=>"TEST1", :member_status=>"TEST1"}
}

puts users.to_yaml

# >> ---
# >> TEST:
# >>   :email_address: TEST
# >>   :member_status: TEST
# >> TEST1:
# >>   :email_address: TEST1
# >>   :member_status: TEST1
```

Basically, it looks like you want an array of hashes, or a hash of hashes. The first will force that the primary keys be unique, whereas the second can allow duplicates. Which is better? That's for you to decide.

And, to account for reality, you need to be able to manage situations where two entirely separate users can have the same name, as there is more than one "John Smith" in the world. That implies using a key that is unique across users; email_address *might* be unique, but it's always possible for two users to share an email address, like in a small company or where they're in the same household.

---

NOTE: Ruby's YAML is built upon Psych, which is where [`load_file`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file) and [`load_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_stream) are defined. Trying to find those in the YAML documentation leads to frustration.

Comment: So what you're telling me is that I would have to make a new Key/Value for each member I add to the YAML? For example: `:username: TEST`, `:username1: TEST1`, etc..

Comment: I'm telling you that your data structure isn't adequate for the job you want it to do. How you want to solve the problem is up to you. I have no idea what requirements there are for the system you want to work with.

Comment: That's where I'm having trouble, I'm at a loss on how to solve the problem, in your personal opinion, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: First, you need to understand how to work with YAML better. I changed the answer to explain the issues. And then you need to discuss with the admins of that site HOW to translate your information into a form they can use. Then you need to accommodate the possible problems of name collisions because there's a big potential for problems there.

Comment: Awh I get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`File.open('users.yml', 'w')` will open `users.yml` and start writing data *at the beginning of the file*, due to the `w` parameter you passed in. See [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode).

What you actually want to do is to search for the specific line in the `users.yml` file and delete that entry in the file.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more please?